Why should I get credentialsUri when I have got a api-key?
When I follow this tuition try to acess gemini, I got a error:

Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials for your environment, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc.

And I did not run these command because I had a api-key
gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID &&
gcloud auth application-default login ACCOUNT

From the gemini api-key page, the api-key is the only param
curl \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"contents":[{"parts":[{"text":"Write a story about a magic backpack"}]}]}' \
  -X POST 'https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-pro:generateContent?key=YOUR_API_KEY'

I want to known did the spring-ai use oauth2 instead of api-key to interact with gemini? Could I replace credentialsUri with api-key in some ways?
Can anyone give me a explanation？ thx!

Your example using the API Key is using the Gemini API. The error message probably comes from code using the Vertex AI.

The issue you are having is that there are two different systems.  Which is confusing and I cant tell you why google did it this way.
Fist you need to understand from the underling AI model standpoint "gemini-pro" is just an ai model.
There are however two different APIs / systems which access it.
Vertex AI
Is the google cloud based version for lack of a better term.  It is not free to use and to use it everything is stored on your Google Cloud account. There for it requires a service account to access it.
Gemini API
Is the system behind Google AI studio. Currently and up until May 02, 2024 see pricing  Gemini Api is free to use.   Gemini API does not require Oauth2 unless you are tuning models.  It runs all off of an api key which you must create on Google AI studio.
anwser
So yes the spring example us using Vertex so is most likely running off of a service account.
Your default credentials were not found
With google cloud you when you sign into your cloud environment via the cli it sets the env var that the Vertex code is looking for.
See: Set up Application Default Credentials

The Gemini API is simpler to use and designed for mobile devices. The Vertex API is designed for backend systems and has more features. Those are just my opinions from working with the APIs and are not from official inputs.

Um no Gemini api is not designed only for mobile devices yes there is a small model for mobile devices but a model is just a model.

I did not mean the Gemini API is only for mobile devices but the first SDKs were for mobile (Android and iOS). That shows their initial focus but now many SDKs are available.

No the first sdks were from Palm and always worked with Python.  thats the first library they created as far as i know and i was part of the early access program for both Gemini and Palm.   all the notebooks came out first.  I have never heard of it as targeting mobile devices.  are you sure your not thinking something diffrent.

Let's take this offline. I am under Google NDA and I think you are also. Send me an email or Twitter PM.
